# Window does not render on build, works fine in development server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder

My app does not display a window when it's built, but works fine when I run `npm run serve`

There is still an process running in task manager, and the same thing happens if I use the installer. I don't get any errors warnings from electron-builder.

background.js:

```js
import { app, protocol, dialog, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, shell } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import childProcess from 'child_process'
import ncp from 'ncp'

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'))
  }

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

I tried the fixes [here](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/commonIssues.html#blank-screen-on-builds-but-works-fine-on-serve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990214/how-to-fix-blank-page-if-i-am-using-vue-router-with-electron-js) to no avail.

I'm using electron-vue. You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/RingComics/ultskylauncher) if you need more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being code present inside of the `app.on('ready')` function. Any additional code needs to be written after the window is created, or the issue occurs.

Comment: I wouldn't think of this by myself... Thanks!